# How to exclude modules dynamically from build using tsconfig file

Tags: angular

I am trying to know, how I can exclude the modules from the build. It can be controlled by through some script or something where while creating the build I can ignore/exclude the modules.
For ex I have three modules A,B,C
Now while building I want to exclude C module.
Kindly help.

Comment: What do you mean with dynamically? What is the exclusion of a module from the build based on?

Comment: @MikeOne I meant to say, if there is a script I can write for making build and having an option to exclude some of the modules. Even though, let's forget that part, how we can exclude some of the modules while making a build ?

Answer (score 0):

according to [tree shaking algorithm](https://indepth.dev/posts/1258/a-gentle-introduction-into-tree-shaking-in-angular-ivy) that is used when building angular app, you don't have to exclude dependencies that are not required in your final bundle. If you are going to exclude dependencies that is required in your app, I am not sure if it is possible.